# Filtering list items based on url depth in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am learning MVC. After a long try and no success, I am here for your help.

I am working on a hobby project, channel guide site, which lists channels with language and category.

URL: `Channel/English`, show english language channels
URL: `Channel/Sports`, show channels fall in sports category.
URL: `Channel/English/Sports`, show english channels which falls in sports category
URL: `Channel/Sports/English`, show channels fall in sports category whose language is english

Controller name: `ChannelController`
Action method code as follows

```
public ActionResult Index(string language = "All", string category = "All")
{
    List<ViewModel.ChannelIndex> list = client.GetList(1, language, category);
    return View(list);
 }
```

Below is my HTML code which generates div for each channel

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultLanguageFirst", new { language = channel.LanguageId })">@channel.LanguageName</a>  
    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultCategoryFirst", new { category = channel.CategoryId })">@channel.CategoryName</a>
</div>
```

Below is the code from RouteConfig

```
           routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultLanguageFirst",
                url: "{controller}/{language}/{category}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Channel", action = "Index", language = UrlParameter.Optional, category = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultCategoryFirst",
                url: "{controller}/{category}/{language}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Channel", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional, language = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I can feel I am doing something wrong.
By the way, I also tried with `@Html.ActionLink` instead of `@Url.RouteUrl` and result is same.

My questions as follows:
1) How to handle these requests in single action method.
2) why `@Url.RouteUrl` does not differentiate based on mapRoute name i.e., between `DefaultLanguageFirst` & `DefaultCategoryFirst`
3) Is it really possible to filter based on what I am trying.

Can someone please help me to understand where I went wrong or any resources which I can refer to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is not working as per your expectation?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I added my doubts/issue for your reference. Please have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never route how you want it to! You could have one route like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultStuffRoute",
    url: "Channel/{category}/{language}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Channel", action = "Index", language = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

And then only use

- URL: Channel/Sports, show channels fall in sports category.
- URL: Channel/Sports/English, show channels fall in sports category whose language is english

With your way you're saying

```
channel/<string>/<string>
```

for both of your routes, asp will never be able to work out if the first string is a category or the language.

**UPDATE**
When it comes to filtering in MVC or indeed WebAPI I would consider using query string parameters.

- Url: channels/cnn/  -  all shows for the CNN channel
- Url: channels/cnn/?lang=en  -  all shows for the CNN channel that are in
  english
- URL: channels/cnn/?cat=sports  -  all shows for CNN channel
  that are related to sports
- URL: channels/cnn/?lang=en&cat=sports  - 
  all shows for CNN that are in english and related to sports

Comment: So, it is impossible to achieve what I expect?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible, because MVC doesn't know that the word 'English' is a language and it doesn't know that 'Sports' is a category all it sees it two words

Comment: Thanks matt, that makes some sense. I better try with different action methods.